# Java order of operations?

Tags: java

I just recently started java and I don't understand the issue I am having here. The output of this program is supposed to be 22.9.... however it doesn't output that when mathematically it should. Any help with why this is this way would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class Playground {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.print((24*1.6)/(6035/3600));
            }
    }
```

Comment: change 6035 to 6035.0 and 6300 to 6300.0

Comment: What does it print ?

Comment: Thank you very much, I looked at the linked question and it explained your answer some more.